# What's the difference between "Syntax of mail function" and "mail function syntax"

Tags: grammar

I am little bit confused about what is the correct sentence of following statements.

```
Syntax of mail function
```

OR

```
mail function syntax
```

Both are correct then Why ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of words with and without the definite article](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27192/order-of-words-with-and-without-the-definite-article). In that case the examples are **File Menu** and **Menu File**, but the syntactic principle is the same.

Comment: In the possible duplicate, the examples are “The File menu” and “Menu File”. I don’t know enough about syntactic principles to comment on whether or not the possible inclusion of “of” is the same as the possible inclusion of “the”, but I’m fairly certain that OP will not find the issue in this question resolved by the answer to that one. That answer starts with that querant’s incorrect substitution, declares it “awkward”, re-introduces the definite article whose absence was the subject of the question, then makes example-specific suggestions on the authority of “should” and “opinion”.

Comment: I don't know it is duplicate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A confusion may arise when words can function as nouns or as adjectives and there is no difference in their appearance.

The **mail function** is comprised of programming statements that perform a certain behavior. The function has a signature that consists of its name and the arguments or parameters that can be fed to it. The invocation of the mail function requires a specific syntax.

Thus, we can speak of the syntax required to invoke the mail function in two ways:

(1) the mail function syntax

where "mail function" is used adjectivally, and

(2) the syntax of the mail function

where the phrase "of the mail function" is used *possessively*, that is, the syntax that is *proper to* the invocation of mail function.